# How to save a file into a buffer?

Tags: python-3.x, webdav

I am trying to parse some xml files via  a webdav interfaces using [webdavclient3](https://pypi.org/project/webdavclient3/).

There is a resource API section where the author claims that you can read/write a file into a buffer.

```
res1 = client.resource("dir1/file1")
res1.read_from(buffer)
res1.write_to(buffer)
```

What is the buffer stands for and how i can create one so i do not need to save the file localy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Example for pickle file

```
import io
import pickle
from webdav3.client import Client

buffer = io.BytesIO()
client.resource("path_to_pickle_file").write_to(buffer)
data = pickle.loads(buffer.getvalue())
print(data)
```